# How can hook mongo result after find function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanna create a hook function when client search any query in database and tried to use [`Mongo.watch()`](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nodejs-change-streams-triggers/)

Reference code:

```
mongo.db
  .watch([{ $match: { operationType: 'insert' } }])
  .on("change", (next) => {
    console.log("@@", next);
  });
```

It is working when I using `.insert()` and `.update()`, as I know that is working for data changed but not for `.find()`.

How can i hook query after find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally and mark down the code base here.

[`Mongo.watch()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/#mongodb-method-db.collection.watch) only notifies on data changes that have persisted to a majority of data-bearing members as the document (update, delete, insert).

Try to use [`Command Monitoring`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/v4.0/fundamentals/monitoring/command-monitoring/?_ga=2.128793740.1472491285.1667279874-70158122.1636096113)to monitor the success or failure of commands sent to Mongo Database.

Example:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const mongo_client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost", { monitorCommands:true });

mongo_client.on('commandStarted', (event) => {
  if(["find", "aggregate"].includes(event.commandName)){
    console.log({
      requestId: event.requestId,
      database: event.databaseName,
      commanName: event.commandName,
      collection: (event.commandName=="find")? event.command.find : event.command.aggregate, 
      query: (event.commandName=="find")? event.command.filter : event.command.pipeline
    })
  }
})
mongo_client.on('commandStarted', (event) => {
  if(["find", "aggregate"].includes(event.commandName)){
    console.log({
      requestId: event.requestId,
      result: event.reply.cursor.firstBatch
    })
  }
})
```